# PHP mail keeps hanging

Tags: php, email, ssmtp

From php.ini

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t
```

The code, which keeps hanging in the browser (I even changed this file to 777)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try{
        mail('question@stackoverflow.com', 'test', 'test');
}Catch(Exception $ex){
        echo 'Exception: ', var_dump($ex, true);
}
echo "Done";
?>
```

Following works perfectly from terminal

```
sendmail -v question@stackoverflow.com
TO: question@stackoverflow.com
FROM: question@stackoverflow.com
SUBJECT: test

test
CTRL+D
```

(Sidenote: I am testing with UFW stopped)

Comment: why are you using normal mail why not phpmailer?

Comment: Well, what does "hanging in the browser" mean? Certainly the php script will only continue when the `mail()` function returns. So if that really takes to long in your eyes, then you should track down what takes so long for sendmail to deliver.

Comment: Oh, and you _did_ check the http servers log files, didn't you?

Comment: mail logs and php logs both said the same --- ssmtp: Connection lost in middle of processing

Comment: @ripa php.net link of phpmailer ?

Comment: @Terence no. I am posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the port from 465 to 587 inside /etc/ssmtp/smtp.conf and it works.

(Good enough for me)

Answer (score 1):

check this [example](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsendmail) for phpmailer. From here You will get example. 
And You can download phpmailer class from github.

check this [github link](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) link for download.

Comment: @Terence if You think this answer works for You then plz accept this answer.